# PayPal REST API with Notifications

Tags: rest, paypal, notifications

PayPal has recently released a new API which should replace the old API. The new API is based on a REST approach.

As fare as I can see there is no option to define a callback URL. In the old API the parameter was 'notify_url'. I use the following documentation:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-payment

Is there a parameter in the new REST API which allows to define a notification URL?

Comment: there is no need for call back. You should think of RESTful service as a function call. You call a function with a set of parameters and you receive a response (maybe in form of Json) which consists of multiple properties. There are hoowever a set of Redirect Urls that you should use: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/

Comment: He's referring to IPN, and yes, there's still a big need for it.  It's one of the most under-utilized features PayPal offers, and it's still very viable with the REST API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, the REST API is still pretty far behind the classic API's with all of the features they provide.  To my knowledge, notify_url/NOTIFYURL simply aren't included in the REST API yet.

That said, if you have IPN configured in your PayPal account profile the REST API calls should still trigger them.  It's just that you can't override the value there with a custom one using notify like you're talking about.

The classic API's aren't going away, though.  You can still use them just fine.

Comment: thanks for the hint where to set the IPN url! why can't paypal write that in their docs?

Comment: It's in the docs under [Instant Payment Notification -> Setup](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/).  ;)